# HTML files on a distant server don't actualise after modification

Tags: html, networking, server, refresh

I'm working on an assignment for school, my files for the website are stored on a distant server which I access via VPN and remote server connection on macOS.

When I modify my html files, the changes aren't reflected immediately, sometimes after a day or two (in fact quite randomly, can be an afternoon, an hour).

It's a bit problematic when you try to have long code sessions. Sometimes, one page actualises but not the others.

I'm not having any problems with my php files, they actualise immediately.

I've tried several things without any changes:

- Emptying the cache
- Trying on different web browsers
- Disconnecting from the server and VPN
- Waiting :)

System infos :

- macOS 10.12.2
- Safari 10.0.2

Thanks for the help, I personally think it's a problem with the server, but I won't be able to change that, hopefully, it's something I can fix.

Comment: Sounds like a server issue, try rebooting the server if it's yours. The nature of this question also seems to adhere to networking, so this could be a better question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Network Engineering.](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Try posting onto one of the mentioned SE sites for a better answer, since this does not sound like a problem defined by the FAQ. Therefore, I'm flagging for off-topic. No offense, I think this is just the wrong place to ask ;)

Comment: @arby36 While the question might get answers on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions) or other sites, I would disagree that it's off topic here. The Help section mentions questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers; and [..] practical, answerable problem[s] unique to software development" as on topic. In addition, I have the same problems, though not as bad as the OP's.

Comment: Okay, thank you anyway for the answers, as I'm sure you have guessed, I'm new here. I will pay attention next time. I have finished my working assignment, so can't do anything now but I would have certainly liked to know what caused such problems .